# Change order of a plist

Tags: xcode, plist

I've made a plist with a bunch of strings. Now it turned out that I have written the strings in the wrong way. I want all the strings to the right be placed left and all the strings to left be placed to right. Is it possible?

[image: Here's an example]

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to do this -

1. You need to do all the stuff manually.
2. You can have a script which will do this task for you. For similar sample scripts you can refer - http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=20152

Nothing as such is available in Xcode to do this for you.

Comment: Might be you can check for this - http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14363/plistedit-pro/, it might help you.